# Multiple Attributes Html.BeginForm MVC id and enctype as part of file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, multipartform-data, enctype

As part of file upload (ASP.NET MVC3) adding id and enctype attributes to HTML.BeginForm return HttpPostedFileBase as null

Model:

```
public class ProfileModel
{
 [UIHint("Upload")]
 public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
}`
```

ProfileForm.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Profile", new { ProfileId = ViewBag.ProfileID }, FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "ProfileForm" }))
{

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.ImageUpload)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.ImageUpload, new { type = "file" })
    </div>
    <div class='buttons'>
        <input type="submit"  value='Save' />
    </div>
}
```

Controller

```
public Upload(ProfileModel viewModel)
{
  if (viewModel.ImageUpload != null && viewModel.ImageUpload.ContentLength > 0)
 {
   var uploadDir = "~/uploads";
   var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(uploadDir), viewModel.ImageUpload.FileName);
   var imageUrl = Path.Combine(uploadDir, viewModel.ImageUpload.FileName);
   viewModel.ImageUpload.SaveAs(imagePath);
   }
}
```

---

if I remove the `@id = "ProfileForm"` attribute as below I am getting the HttpPostedFileBase (ImageUpload) value.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Profile", new { ProfileId = ViewBag.ProfileID }, FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{  }
```

I need to pass both id and enctype - can anyone please suggest me what I am doing wrong or is there any better way to do ?

Comment: What do you mean _I need to pass id_? Using `new { @id = "ProfileForm" }` is adding an `id` attribute to the form. Its not 'passing' anything

Comment: Thank you for correcting Stephen, technically if add new {@id="ProfileForm"} to Html.BeginForm () it will resolve to Form element with id attribute.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. But is there any reason why you need to gve the form an `id` attribute anyway? And why do you have `[UIHint("Upload")]` (you not using `EditorFor()` so its just ignored). Note also your adding `ProfileID` as a route parameter which will post back - I assume that your model also includes a property named `ProfileID`?

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I found the issue. When the submit button is clicked I am searializing the form data which failed to serialize image as part of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by doing below:
- When the submit is clicked I am positing the image first separately by calling below method

```
 function FileUploadClick() {

            var formData = new FormData();
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];

                formData.append("FileUpload", file);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Profile/Upload',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('succes!!');
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("errror");
                }
            });
        }

function Submit() {

    $("#ProfileForm").submit(function (e) {
        FileUploadClick();
        var url = "/Profile/Update";
        $.post(url, $("#ProfileForm").serialize(), function (data) {

        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After wasting a lot of time I thing its helpful to you.Just use this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Profile", new { @id = "ProfileForm" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data",  }))
```

your id will be there new { @id = "ProfileForm" }

Answer (score 0):

Try to removing @ from id and enctype

Comment: I have tried below and still the image upload value is null:

1. 'Removed @ from -- new { id = "ProfileForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}'

2. Removed @ & enctype  -- new { id = "ProfileForm"}